# Selenium is reading placeholder value

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation

I am running some tests using Selenium and in one of the test I check if a value in a box is equal to zero. The problem is that when I run the test normally it fails because it is always getting a value equal to zero, but when I run it with debugging step by step it gets a value different to zero and it passes.

I came to the conclusion that the page is using a placeholder value of zero meanwhile it gets the real number from the database. Is there a way to get the real value of the text?

Comment: Is there any element or loader that will help you discover whether the data load is completed or not?

Answer (score 0):

Have you waited for the page to completely load ? Have you tried adding few wait seconds before retrieving the text value from your element ? If you have tried these already and even then you are getting the same issue, share your code here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have WaitEnabled element which will wait till element load

```
 @Test

 public void test() throws InterruptedException, IOException 

 {   

  //To wait for element visible

  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);

  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='text3']")));

  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='text3']")).sendKeys("Text box is visible now");

  System.out.print("Text box text3 is now visible");

    }
```